# Flink: stateful access in RichAsyncFunction?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The Flink [documentation for RichAsyncFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/async/RichAsyncFunction.html) states:

> State related apis in RuntimeContext are not supported yet because the key may get changed while accessing states in the working thread.

What exactly does this mean?  Which calls are permitted and which are not? What will happen if calls are made to an unsupported method?

The documentation for `RuntimeContext` is [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RuntimeContext.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichAsyncFunction` provides its own subclass of `RuntimeContext`, which throws `UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to access any state.